# installation stuck at language selection page

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

Asus x541UJ
Nvidia graphics.
I used Rufus to create bootable pendrive, but it got stuck at the Welcome page.

[image]

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: Already check same pendrive with other laptop iso file is perfectly working

Answer (score 0):

This issue have been repeatedly reported, for some reason NVIDIA GPUs and the newer generation of intel CPUs face really serious graphical failures, there's a process to solve this issue in the newer releases.

But in the meantime you can select the "Safe graphics" option from the boot menu and most likely this will resolve the issue, I also recommend disconnecting the computer from the internet for maximum performance. But keep in mind you might have to install important updates and drivers after the installation is completed

Comment: Even with safe mode got the same error. It got stuck at language page for indefinite hours....

Comment: Then chances are the USB stick is at fault here, please try to format the USB to FAT32 and download Ubuntu on the usb again or if possible use a different usb.